# (Why) is the norm of a RKHS positive definite?

Tags: reference-request, normed-spaces, covariance, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

$
\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}
$
A $\color{red}{\text{(strictly)}}$ positive definite kernel $k: \real^d\times \real^d \to \real$ satisfies for all $x_i \in \real^d$, $a=(a_1,\dots, a_n)\in \real^d$
$$
   \sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_j k(x_i, x_j) \ge 0 \quad \color{red}{>0 \iff  a\neq 0}
$$
The reproducing kernel hilbertspace (RKHS) $H=H(k)$ of kernel $k$ is then defined as the *closure* of
$$
S = \Bigl\{
u: \real^d\to\real
\;:\; u = \sum_{i=1}^n a_ik(x_i, \cdot), a_i \in \real, x_i\in \real^d, n\ge 1\Bigr\}
$$
where the *closure*  is with respect to the norm $\|\cdot\|_H$ induced by the dot product defined by the bilinear extension of
$$
\langle k(x_i, \cdot), k(x_j, \cdot\rangle_H = k(x_i, x_j).
$$
I have two questions:

1. Is this norm $\|\cdot\|_H$ really a norm (i.e. does positive definiteness hold, in the sense that $\|u\|_H = 0$ implies $u=0$?
2. If yes in general or assuming the kernel is strictly positive definite, how can you show that? I would think that this should be wrong if the kernel is not strictly positive definite, but maybe I don't see something important and literature (e.g. [Adler (2007)](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-0-387-48116-6)) calls $\|\cdot\|_H$ a norm without proof). And I could not find an actual proof.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that $\| \cdot \|{H}$ is defined as $\| x \|{H} := \sqrt{\langle x, x \rangle_{H}}$ with $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{H}$ being an inner product. Since for an inner product, we have $\langle x, x\rangle = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$, we conclude that:
$$ \| x \|{H} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \langle x, x\rangle = 0 \Longleftrightarrow x = 0 $$ which proves that $\| x \|{H}$ is positive definite. The property is thus independent of the kernel.

However, in the context of function spaces, it is crucial to note that "=" here means "almost everywhere".

Comment: I mean yes, but that only moves the question to the positive definiteness of the inner product. Which is the question I want answered. I mean a covariance could be zero somewhere right? I.e. the kernel could be zero somewhere, i.e. the inner product could be zero

Comment: I assume you are referring to the following equation $\langle k(x_{i}, \cdot), k_(x_{j}, \cdot) \rangle =k(x_{i},x_{j})$. Usually RKHS arise as a subset of a Hilbert space ($\| \cdot \|_{H}$ is the norm of this Hilbert space) and then the equation is a consequence of the Riesz representation theorem, i.e. that every bounded linear functional can be written in terms of the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{H}$. This way is covered in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reproducing_kernel_Hilbert_space#Definition).